# How can I log test-specific infomation when implementing TestCaseExtension?

Tags: kotlintest

In a `TestCaseExtension`, I want to log test-specific information. At first sight, doing it like this seems to work:

```
import io.kotlintest.*
import io.kotlintest.extensions.SpecLevelExtension
import io.kotlintest.extensions.TestCaseExtension
import io.kotlintest.specs.DescribeSpec

class MySpec : DescribeSpec({
    describe("bar") {
        it("a") {}
        it("b") {}
    }
}) {
    override fun extensions(): List<SpecLevelExtension> = listOf(MyExtension())
}

class MyExtension : TestCaseExtension {

    override suspend fun intercept(
        testCase: TestCase,
        execute: suspend (TestCase, suspend (TestResult) -> Unit) -> Unit,
        complete: suspend (TestResult) -> Unit
    ) {
        execute(testCase) { testResult ->
            if (testCase.type == TestType.Test) {
                println(testCase.description.name)
            }
            complete(testResult)
        }
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ IDEA, the output for the first test is "Scenario: a" and the output for the second test is "Scenario: b". However, when changing `describe("bar")` to `describe("foo")`, the output for the first test becomes "Scenario: a[newline]Scenario: b", while the output for the second test becomes empty.

So, how can I properly assign logged information to each test? Maybe using `println` is not even the right choice?

---

- io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.2.1
- JDK 10.0.2
- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: Changing from `bar` to `foo` caused this? This is odd

Comment: Yes. The behavior depends on the names of the describe and the it.

Comment: I'll take a look into it

Comment: I can't duplicate this. If I use your code it prints out Scenario: a\nScenario: b which is what I would expect.

Comment: "Scenario: a\nScenario: b" is the undesired output for the first test.